# Display text/banner if AdView cant loaded

Tags: android, layout, view, admob

I try to display a banner / text if the AdView fails to load (because of AdBlock or anything else).

I tried different methods:

- Two RelativeLayouts above (both were hidden from AdBlock ...)
- Set a text view in the RelativeLayout which contain my AdView to visible if App Fails to load.
- and different layout tricks

nothing works. 
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the [AdListener](http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/intermediate.html#adlistener) interface to listen for AdMob events.

```
public interface AdListener {
  public void onReceiveAd(Ad ad);
  public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad ad, AdRequest.ErrorCode error);
  public void onPresentScreen(Ad ad);
  public void onDismissScreen(Ad ad);
  public void onLeaveApplication(Ad ad);
}
```

Then you will want your AdView to listen to the AdListener.

```
// Assuming AdView is named adView and this class implemented AdListener.
adView.setAdListener(this);
```

In particular, you will be interested in the the onFailedToReceiveAd callback.  This called if AdMob failed to load an ad.  If you implement this method, you can take appropriate action in your application when an ad is not returned.

Comment: I used this, but it doesnt show my textview or my layout. Any idea?

Comment: If you were going off my answer only and not the documentation, I forgot to show you how to tell the AdView to listen to the AdListener.  I updated my answer accordingly.  If you had already done this, can you verify if the AdListener is working by logging something to LogCat in the `onFailedToReceiveAd` event and checking if it gets logged when running your app?

Comment: The AdListener works. :)
It seems that the AdBlock Block it in a way.